# Mostrar bien el numero de elementos en paginacion

Tags: javascript, reactjs, paginacion

estoy haciendo un componente en el que incluye paginacion. En el tengo que añadir el numero de elemetos del total que hay.

"Se muestran x elementos de x que hay en total".

Para la paginacion utilizo las variables:

**Currentpage** (numero de paginas totales que hay)

**itemPage** (numero de elementos por pagina).

En mi caso, mi data tiene 30 elementos, es decir **"cerveza.length"** **= 30**.

Tengo el siguiente h1:

```
<h1>
                {`mostrando ${(currentpage+1)*itemPage} de ${cerveza.length} disponisbles`}
              </h1>
```

Todo bien hasta la ultima pagina, que me muestra " MOSTRANDO 32 DE 30", ya que hace la multiplicacion y tendria que aparecer 30.

como puedo solucionarlo?

Gracias!

Comment: que herramienta estas usando para la paginacion?

Comment: javascript normal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <div className='flex justify-center mb-3'>
                { (currentpage+1)*itemPage <= cerveza.length?

                <h1>
                  {`Mostrando ${(currentpage + 1) * itemPage} de ${cerveza.length} disponisbles`}
                </h1>
                :
                <h1>
                {`Mostrando ${cerveza.length} de ${cerveza.length} disponisbles`}
              </h1>

                }
              </div>
```

Comment: ¿Esto es una respuesta o debía ser una edición de tu pregunta?

Answer (score 0):

Imaginemos que tienes una lista con 30 elementos y quieres mostrar 8 elementos por página:

- La primera página muestra los elementos 1 a 8
- La segunda página muestra los elementos de 9 a 16
- Etcétera

Sabiendo que los arrays comienzan por 0, usaré internamente 0 como la primera página. Por tanto para todas las páginas menos la última puedo usar una simple multiplicación para calcular los elementos, pero en la última página no muestro 8 elementos sino 6 (4 * 8 = 32), me sobran dos líneas. Así que tengo que comprobar que el número final no es mayor que el número total de elementos:

```js
const pageSize = 8;
let cerveza = { length: 30};

let currentPage = 0;

let start=0, end=0;

while (end < cerveza.length) {
  start = (currentPage * pageSize) + 1;
  end = Math.min((currentPage +1) * pageSize ,cerveza.length);
  console.log(`Página ${currentPage+1}: elementos ${start} a ${end}`);
  currentPage++;
}
```